# Animating recursive subdivision (Geometry nodes)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I followed this tutorial to simulate recursive subdivision in Blender:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2PkrmpMmQA&t=15s

But I can't figure out how to animate the scale of each instance. What I'm going for is something similar to this, where I can instance any object on the faces of the divided mesh: https://www.instagram.com/p/CMMsfxhhIMW/

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: youtube.com/watch?v=PgZrIToTdJE&t=1042s

A bit more complex than the first approach, but it works by changing the instancing object from the grid to any other object:

[image]